# Extract a code within a column - Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a file that i imported to PowerBI and i need to transform a column, to leave only a code that is present within each cell of that column.

The code is 21 Digits, and starts either with "MB-" or "EX-"

Example of a cell in the column named DATA:

```
Hellow World | MB-4567891G3456D898A2_ehgt_HFT
```

What I need to extract: `MB-4567891G3456D898A2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few options to do that. The most straightforward is to go to Power Query Editor and add a column with the extracted code, either by [adding a custom column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/split-columns-delimiter) with the first 21 characters from the full code or the text before the underscore, or to [split the full code column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-add-custom-column) by delimiter underscore.

The code for the custom columns could use [Text.Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-start) or [Text.BeforeDelimiter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-beforedelimiter) and can be (assuming "Full Code" is the name of the column containing the full code) either:

```
= Text.Start([Full Code], 21)
```

[image]

or

```
= Text.BeforeDelimiter([Full Code], "_")
```

If you prefer to split the existing column, use custom delimiter underscore and split at the left-most delimiter:

[image]

These three methods will give you the following result:

[image]

Of course, you can delete `Full Code.2` column if you want to, and eventually rename `Full Code.1` to something more meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a delimiter between World and MB, you could use the Text.AfterDelimiter function. I´m not a developer so not sure if that´s called a function or what.

In the picture below, I created a custom column called Grade, by extracting a string from a column called Name, after a certain delimiter in entries that appear in the Name column.

[Text.AfterDelimiter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PWO5.png)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! The issue is that the cells don't obey to a specific order. The only common thing is that it starts either with "MB-" or "EX-" and it has 21 characters overall